# Rounding to 5 hundredths according to own rules

Tags: php, rounding

I need to round the price (in euros) based on these 4 rules:

1. the price ends at 1 and 2 cents, is rounded down (e.g. 15.52 is rounded to 15.50).
2. the price ends at 3 and 4 cents, is rounded up to 5 cents (e.g. 15.53 is rounded to 15.55).
3. the price ends at 6 and 7 cents, is rounded down to 5 cents (e.g. 15.57 is rounded to 15.55).
4. the price ends at 8 and 9 cents, is rounded up (e.g. 15.59 is rounded to 15.60)

How do I do this in PHP (using `round`, `ceil` etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: round($value / 0.05) * 0.05